# Intermittent problem using loginPopup MSAL JS in a REACT

Tags: reactjs, authentication, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm using MSAL JS in order to authenticate users in react application developed using REACT. Sometimes login works perfectly, redirecting users to the home page of the app. Other times login popup opens, users insert their login but then login procedure fails with this error:

hash_empty_error: Hash value cannot be processed because it is empty.
Please verify that your redirectUri is not clearing the hash.

I know this issue was raised before but never seen proper solution how to overcome this error

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to set the redirectUri to a blank page or a page that does not implement MSAL. If your application is only using popup and silent APIs you can set this on the PublicClientApplication config like below:

```
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENTID,
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.REACT_APP_TENANTID}`,
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/blank.html'
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage"
    }
}
```

If your application also needs to support redirect APIs you can set the redirectUri on a per request basis:

```
msalInstance.loginPopup({
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/blank.html"
})
```